# How to enable vba macros in an application (Outlook)?

Tags: android, vba, outlook

I have created a vba script which is used to check external recipients(other domains) before sending in outlook and it's working fine in my pc

i wants to implement the same in mobile as well( i have outlook for android, need to add the same vba script)

is it possible ? if so how can i add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA scripts are only supported by the Windows version of Outlook. The Android version of Outlook is a completely separate product that shares no code with the Windows version.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, is there any options to add vba in outlook for android?

Comment: Or any other coding?

Comment: No. It only supports Web addins (JS).